# Reboot freezes at end of Ubuntu 18.10 installation

Tags: system-installation, freeze, reboot, 18.10, inspiron

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.10 on my Dell Inspiron 15 7567 gaming laptop. The installation went normally, but when I need to reboot the system to finish the installation the laptop freezes. This image is from the reboot initialization.

[image: this image]

This image is when the process freezes.

[image: this one]

I'm doing a dual boot installation, so I had deactivate the fastboot from Windows and the Secure Boot, create an unallocated partition of 75 GB, and select the option of installing Ubuntu 18.10 alongside Windows.

Comment: I finally sucessed installing ubuntu, but unfortunately it is the 18.04. I made a bootable USB stick with a reliable kingston to avoid problems and ask my friend to prepare the USB using the ubuntu tool startup disk creator. I will stay with this distro because it is easier and i hadn't lucky with 18.10, i won't risk trying to updatet to 18.10.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem on (probably) the same laptop (in my country it's shipped simply as Dell Inspiron G3 15' with varying specs):

- Intel Core i7-8750H,
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050Ti,
- 32 GB DDR4 RAM,
- dual disc SSD + HDD.

I may add that it came with Windows 10 pre-installed, but I didn't want to keep it, so I didn't even try to set up a dual boot, I've just  formatted the whole disc. Although I did need to change a BIOS setting (RAID to AHCI) for Ubuntu to be able to see the SSD disc.

So if I may add a few points:

1. First I've tried to install Ubuntu 18.10. It has installed fine, but then froze after hitting the restart button on the box saying that the installation is over. I've done a hard reboot and tried to run the OS. It has worked fine, I was able to log in, but immediately after logging in it froze on an empty, this pinkish-violet screen.
2. Then I've tried to reinstall Ubuntu 18.10. I've formatted the disc again and did everything as before, with the exception that I've waited for a few minutes after hitting the restart button on the aforementioned box. And in fact that changed something, because that black screen which OP posted above appeared with exactly the same messages. They've appeared gradually, not all at once, sometimes taking quite a long time, but after that one about "psmouse serio1" at the bottom nothing more happened for over half an hour, so I did a hard reboot again.
3. Then I've decided to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Again I've formatted the disc, again the installation went fine until that very last step when it again froze upon hitting the restart button. This time however, after doing another hard reboot, the OS started fine, I've successfully logged in and was able to work for a minute or two. Unfortunately, after that time the OS froze again and this time I'm out of ideas about what I should do next.

EDIT: I've installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS and it seems to be working fine, although the touchpad lost the ability to recognise "taps", so if one wants to click using it, one needs to physically push it, taps won't do it. For the time being it must suffice, but half-usable touchpad and outdated software notwithstanding, support for Ubuntu 16.04 ends in 4 months, so this isn't a long-term solution.

Comment: Your notebook is a generation younger than mine but basically it's the same. I have the same problems as you when performing the 18.10 installation and have had problems in the past when installing 18.04.

I have an SSD(250GB)+HDD hybrid(1TB) and I am trying to install ubuntu side by side to windows on SSD, the BIOS is already in AHCI.

I honestly don't know where to locate the problems, I will continue to try during the next few months because I need ubuntu for university.

My next step is to try to make a bootable USB stick with a friend's ubuntu. When possible I return what happened.

Comment: I have just tried to install using my friend's bootable pen drive, while rebooting it seems everything was going well but something happened in the middle and ends with the same massage of the mouse.So no ideas, I will try to redo the pen drive and try again

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had the same problem with Ubuntu 18.10 and I have Gtx 1050 on my laptop. It turned out that I just needed to install proprietary driver for my graphics card.
So to boot normally I added `nouveau.modeset=0` to my boot options in grub by pressing `e` during the grub screen.
Then I just went to Software and Update application in Ubuntu and pressed `Search for additional drivers`.
Hope this would help to you. Oh, and Happy New Year!
P.S. I found many problems with Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 on my 2018 laptop - it doesn't show me battery status, don't recognize lid and touchpad doesn't work properly. So I don't even know what to do with all that. Currently I'm on Windows, having Ubuntu 18.10 dual booted and waiting till I manage to make it work normally.

Comment: My problem ist'n related with the screen, my problem happen when I have to reboot after installation and saids that have some problem whit the mouse

Answer (score 0):

The NVIDIA Driver leads to the problem.

1. If it has been frozen, do a hard reboot.
2. When it appears the GRUB selection page, select the ubuntu advanced options, enter.
3. select recovery mode, enter.
4. select grub, enter.
5. select resume, enter.

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, replace "quiet splash" with "quiet splash nomodeset" and save.

Enter `sudo update-grub` and reboot. Everything will be normal.

Translated from: https://www.cnblogs.com/masbay/p/10718514.html.